# Producing a random number that is different each time

Tags: javascript, random

I need to produce a random number ranging between 2 and 5 which is different each time. For example, I don't want two 3's in a row, or two 5's in a row. I then have to feed this into a for() loop, like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < noBoxes.length; i+=randNumber) {
    //....
}
```

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: "I don't want two 3's in a row, or two 5's in a row." - then it would not be random :)

Comment: So your want a random number from a list of numbers and remove this number from the list after you have it?

Comment: jbabey: It wouldn't be an evenly distributed, uncorrelated random number, but it's still stochastic.

Comment: Haha, yes you're right, it wouldn't be exactly random, but I assumed the initial number would be random, and then one would check this and change the second number accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generate a random number up to n-1 and add it on, modulo the original range (shifting because the min is not 0):

```
i = some random int from 2 to 5
delta = randInt(3) // range of possible values from 2 to 5 is 4, minus 1 to
                   // prevent getting all the way round to i again
nextval = (i-2+delta)%4+2  // shift i down by the minimum, add the
                           // delta and modulo the range
```

This works because it adds up to 1 below the range, so it can never get back to the original number. For example, i=3, random int 0 to 2, so the max is (i-2+2)%3+2=3%3+2=0+2=2.

```
function differentRandInt(min,max,current) {
    var shiftedcurrent = current-min;
    var range = max-min+1;
    var delta = Math.floor((Math.random()*(range-1))+1);
    return (shiftedcurrent + delta)%range + min;
}
```

So if i=3, then i-min is 1, the range after adding the delta is 2,3,4, modulo 4 yielding 2,3,0, so adding the min gives us 4,5,2.

Comment: How does that avoid what the OP is trying to avoid?

Comment: It adds on a delta that is limited to below the range (2 to 5). In effect it reduces the range of numbers to all except the current value, without having to re-generate the value if it collides.

Comment: I think there is a little error in your code, currently it won't produce the upper bound.

Comment: @Yoshi: sorry, missed the +1 on the range. As someone said, there are 3 hard problems in computer science: cache invalidation, and off by one errors.

Comment: Nonetheless, this is a really nice solution for this kind of problem. Definitely +1 from me ;)

Answer (score 2):

Edit: more complete solution, and fixed off-by-one error:

```
var prev, randNumber;
for(var i = 0; i < noBoxes.length; i+=randNumber) {
    do {
        randNumber = 2 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
    } while(randNumber === prev);
    prev = randNumber;
}
```

Comment: This very likely produces the same numbers in a row at a lot of points.

Comment: It doesn't need to be iterative! Just limit the range of the random number you generate to the full range minus 1.

Comment: That's a nice idea Phil. Something along the lines of: `produce random number in the range of 1..n-1; if random number == previous number, then random number = n;` (assuming we count from 1...)

Comment: Or, like my answer, use modulo to wrap the range around!

Answer (score 0):

Like so: http://jsbin.com/eyitav/

```
var loopingValues = [2, 3, 4, 5],
    len,
    value,
    rand;

while ( (len=loopingValues.length) ) {
  rand = ~~( ( Math.random() % 1 ) * len);
  value = loopingValues.splice(rand, 1)[0];
  //alert( value )
}
```

Now you have your loop with `value` as the value `2, 3, 4 and 5` in random order.

---

Or easier to read: http://jsbin.com/ejizuw/

```
var loopingValues = [2, 3, 4, 5],
    value,
    rand;

while ( loopingValues.length ) {
  rand = Math.random();
  if ( rand === 1 ) {
    rand = 0;
  }
  rand = rand * loopingValues.length;
  rand = Math.floor(rand);

  value = loopingValues[rand];

  loopingValues.splice(rand, 1);

  alert(value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get your series in an array before you start looping-

```
var noBoxes={length:100};
var R= [2], r= 2, n= 2;
while(R.length<noBoxes.length){
    n= R[R.length-1];
    while(r== n) r= 2+Math.floor(Math.random()*4)
    R.push(r);
}


And then loop through the array-

for(var i = 0; i < noBoxes.length; i+=R[i]) {
    ....
}
```